# Importar objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, poo, javascript-import, exports

Tengo un objeto en un archivo llamado Estudiante.js y quiero importarlo al script principal (script.js) para usarlo como objeto pero me da el error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at script.js:1:1)
```

```
class Estudiante {
    constructor(nombre, edad, notaMedia) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.notaMedia = notaMedia;
    }

    get nombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    set nombre(nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    get edad() {
        return this.edad;
    }

    set edad(edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    get notaMedia() {
        return this.notaMedia;
    }

    set notaMedia(notaMedia) {
        this.notaMedia = notaMedia;
    }

    getData() {
        return "Nombre: " + this.nombre + ",\nEdad: " + this.edad + ",\nNota Media: " + this.notaMedia;
    }
}

export { Estudiante };
```

```js
import "./Estudiante";

var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
var edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;
var nota = document.getElementById("notaMedia").value;

document.getElementById("boton").onclick = function (e) {
    if (nombre == null || edad == null || nota == null) {
        alert("Datos incorrectos");
    } else {
        let estudiante = new Estudiante(nombre, edad, nota);
        alert(estudiante.getData());
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Objetos</title>
</head>

<body>
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="" id="nombre"><br>
    Edad: <input type="text" name="" id="edad"><br>
    Nota Media: <input type="text" name="" id="notaMedia"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Almacenar">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Para que el navegador reconozca que se trata de un módulo, debes trabajar con los atributos adecuados de la sintaxis HTML: `<script src"..." type="module">`. Además, por razones de seguridad, los módulos no trabajan si los archivos son servidos de forma local, deben ser servidos mediante un servidor Web. [Más en la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: Pero Estudiante.js no lo llamo desde el html, también tengo que poner un
```script src "..." type="module"```?
Y con lo segundo que has dicho, quieres decir que no puedo hacerlo con importaciones?

Comment: Quiero decir, si tengo que hacerlo todo en el mismo archivo no pasa nada, pero quería tener un poco de orden separando los objetos en diferentes archivos

Comment: En tu HTML cargas **sólo** el módulo `main.js` de esta forma: `<script src="main.js" type="module">`. Y dentro del código de `main.js` haces todas las importaciones que necesites. Ahora, esto funciona sólo si los ficheros han sido servidos mediante un servidor Web, es decir, si tu barra de direcciones para el HTML en el navegador apunta a un recurso de tipo: `file://ruta/al/html/local`, entonces la carga de módulos no funciona. Saludos

Comment: Ya veo, una pena... Entonces lo hare todo en el mismo archivo, gracias